# How to evaluate the following (rather complex) integral between $x=0$ and $x=\infty$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I've found a function that describes the concentration function of a polymer around a sphere. I want to evaluate the following integral that contains that function but I'm not sure how to go about it. Can someone send me in the right direction/help me out. Thanks in advance.

$$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty4\pi(x+R)^2\left(1-\left(\frac{\frac{x}{R}+\tanh{\frac{x+p}{D}}}{\frac{x}{R}+1}\right)^2\right)dx$$

Comment: Is $D=2R$ ? Let me know

Comment: No, $D$ is independent of $R$. For a physical interpretation, $R$ is the radius of the sphere and $D$ is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}R_\text{gyration}$ where $R_\text{gyration}$ is the gyration radius of the polymer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the antiderivative, if we expand the integrand (as @A-Level Student did), it is
$$4 \pi  R^2+8 \pi  R x-8 \pi  R x \tanh
   \left(\frac{p+x}{D}\right)-4 \pi  R^2 \tanh ^2\left(\frac{p+x}{D}\right)$$

For the difficult antiderivatives, let $x=Dt-p$ to face
$$I_1=\int x \tanh
   \left(\frac{p+x}{D}\right)\,dx=D^2\int  t \tanh (t)\,dt-D p \int\tanh (t)\,dt$$
$$\int  t \tanh (t)\,dt=\frac{1}{2} \left(t \left(t+2 \log \left(e^{-2
   t}+1\right)\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-e^{-2 t}\right)\right)$$
$$\int   \tanh (t)\,dt=\log (\cosh (t))$$

$$I_2=\int\tanh ^2\left(\frac{p+x}{D}\right)\,dt=D \int\tanh ^2(t)\,dt=D (t-\tanh (t))$$

Now, we can easily go back to $x$ but the problem is to compute the limits.

**Edit**

Aking a CAS to compute the limits, the result for
$$I= \displaystyle\int_0^\infty4\pi(x+R)^2\left(1-\left(\frac{\frac{x}{R}+\tanh{\frac{x+p}{D}}}{\frac{x}{R}+1}\right)^2\right)dx$$ is
$$\frac{3 }{2 \pi  R}I=
D \left(\pi ^2 D+6 R\right)+12 p^2-3 D^2 \log ^2\left(1+e^{\frac{2 p}{D}}\right)-$$ $$6 D \left(D\,
   \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\tanh
   \left(\frac{p}{D}\right)+1\right)\right)+R \tanh
   \left(\frac{p}{D}\right)\right)$$

Comment: I've let mathematica solve the integral and it gave the following solution: $4D\pi R(\frac{2R}{1+Exp{\frac{2p}{D}}}-D \text{Polylog}_2(-Exp{-\frac{2p}{D}}))$. Maybe that can give some inspiration on how to go about computing these limits.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\frac{\frac{x}{R}+\tanh{\frac{x+p}{D}}}{\frac{x}{R}+1}\equiv\frac{x+R\tanh\frac{x+p}{D}}{x+R}$$
$$\implies1-\left(\frac{\frac{x}{R}+\tanh{\frac{x+p}{D}}}{\frac{x}{R}+1}\right)^2\equiv1-\frac{x^2+2Rx\tanh\frac{x+p}{D}+R^2\tanh^2\frac{x+p}{D}}{(x+R)^2}$$
$$\equiv\frac{2Rx+R^2-2Rx\tanh{\frac{x+p}{D}}-R^2 \tanh^2{\frac{x+p}{D}}}{(x+R^2)}$$
$$\implies\pi(x+R)^2\left(1-\left(\frac{\frac{x}{R}+\tanh{\frac{x+p}{D}}}{\frac{x}{R}+1}\right)^2\right)\equiv\pi(x+R)^2\frac{2Rx+R^2-2Rx\tanh{\frac{x+p}{D}}-R^2 \tanh^2{\frac{x+p}{D}}}{(x+R^2)}$$
which simplifies nicely, and then the integral is easy to evaluate.

If you need anymore help please ask :)

Comment: I would like to know the limits of the "not-so-simple" antiderivative. Any idea ?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get quite far on the way but encoured some function which I've never seen before like the polylogarithm. I'll need to read more into it but your simplification helped to get me further along! Thanks.

Comment: @MM glad to help, I forgot about the limits, and I thought integration by parts would work on part of the integrand when in fact it didn't, so it really wasn't as simple as I thought at all.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I forgot about the limits, sorry, I have no idea how to compute it.